# Clarification on Heisenberg thought experiment

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, thought-experiment

Heisenberg imagined a high energy photon was absorbed by an electron, but in order to make a measurement on that electron it will have to absorb another photon which means it velocity gets higher but what does it have to do with uncertainty principle, I must have missed something here? Does it means he could not measure the correct velocity without adding new photon into the picture?

Comment: Are you talking about [Heisenberg's microscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg%27s_microscope)?

Comment: @PM2Ring: yes that's the one gamma Ray microscope

Comment: Reread the common description of that thought exp. It should involve one electron and one photon.  Not that this should necessarily solve your problem but the question might get clearer.

Comment: @Alchimista: I read it but I kept thinking it was measurement that produce this uncertainty which I believe is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Many (including Bohr) have critcized Heisenberg's gamma ray microscope thought experiment because it makes it seem like the electron has a definite position before it's measured, and that the uncertainty arises simply because any method of measurement must disturb that position. But quantum mechanics denies that the electron has a definite position before an attempt to locate it has been made.

In Heisenberg's defence, quantum theory was still very new, and everyone in the field was struggling to wrap their heads around the implications of the mathematics. Also bear in mind that Heisenberg (and many other scientists of that era) believed in the philosophy of logical [Positivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positivism). In that philosophy, *all* knowledge derives from observation and measurement, and the very idea of a particle having properties independent of observation is considered to be meaningless.